# Vuforia occlusion management sample

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, occlusion

I am new to augmented reality and trying to run Vuforia sample in Unity. I am using windows 7 32 bit. I downloaded occlusion management sample from unity site : [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples) and imported  OcclusionManagement-6-2-10.unitypackage into a new project. I am also attaching a screenshot of my Unity editor. I could not locate sufficient documentation on what to do next, tried running the project as is. Nothing happens when i do that. Some posts pointed that i should add relevant scenes to my project and run them. I added Vuforia 3 Occlusion scene to project and ran them. Now the camera opens. The output is very similar when i create a new project and just add an ARCamera and run it. Will anyone be able to explain if i am missing some steps in running this sample and if i need to do anything additional. Also, documents dont appear to be explaining what is the exact output of this sample, so if any of you are aware of documentation that explains what is expected when this sample runs successfully and how I can see occlusion management features, that would be very helpful.
[image]

[image]